# how to get the value of option values on select change in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a select list in html and I want to get the select values in a textbox. For this I have done the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myDropdown").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#txtBox").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"))
    });
   });
    </script>

<table id="tab1">
    <tr>
        <td>Select Affiliate Source:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="myDropdown">
                <option value="vcom">Vcommission</option>
                <option value="pym">Payoom</option>
                <option value="snpdl">Snapdeal</option>
                <option value="flpkrt">Flipkart</option>
            </select>
            <div><input id="txtBox" type="text"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But while selecting the value in select the textbox is not showing any value.

Comment: @sharique ansari: The code clearly **doesn't** use `ready`, so attempting to edit it to make it do so is actively harmful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can include your code in the `$(document).ready()`
2. You already have the selected value in `selectedValue`, no need to use `find()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myDropdown").change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $("#txtBox").val(selectedValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<table id="tab1">
  <tr>
    <td>Select Affiliate Source:</td>
    <td>
      <select id="myDropdown">
        <option value="vcom">Vcommission</option>
        <option value="pym">Payoom</option>
        <option value="snpdl">Snapdeal</option>
        <option value="flpkrt">Flipkart</option>
      </select>
      <div>
        <input id="txtBox" type="text">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not rude to say that it's unuseful to try to be the fastest gun in the west by posting incomplete answers. Re being deliberate: You mean you didn't mean to click Post? It was a mouse click error or something? C'mon... :-)

Comment: Anyway, it's not worth a lot of back-and-forth. Just a friendly word is all that was meant.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the value in `selectedValue`, no need for the `find`:

```
$("#myDropdown").change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $("#txtBox").val(selectedValue);
});
```

Separately, the code *as shown in your question* will try to access the `select` element before it exists, and won't attach a `change` handler to it. I don't know if that's really how your code is arranged, but if so, that's a problem as well. Script code only has access to elements defined *before* it runs. You need to either move that `script` tag *below* the `select` tag (usually just before the ending `</body>` tag is best), or use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) callback (but only if you don't control where the script tags go).

Here's a complete example, in order:

```html
<table id="tab1">
    <tr>
        <td>Select Affiliate Source:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="myDropdown">
                <option value="vcom">Vcommission</option>
                <option value="pym">Payoom</option>
                <option value="snpdl">Snapdeal</option>
                <option value="flpkrt">Flipkart</option>
            </select>
            <div><input id="txtBox" type="text"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $("#myDropdown").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#txtBox").val(selectedValue);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready), as your DOM is loaded after your jquery code, so that your element event not applied,

```
$(function(){
    $("#myDropdown").change(function () {
        $("#txtBox").val(this.value); // sometimes core javascript functionality more easy to use
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code below, it should provide the desired result.

To retrieve the value of a `select` element in jQuery, you only need to call the `val()` function of the element as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myDropdown").change(function () {
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();
      $("#txtBox").val(selectedValue);
  });
})
```

**Source**: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

Script should be execute after the full page load or you can move the script at the end of the page. Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myDropdown").change(function () {
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();
      $("#txtBox").val(selectedValue);
  });
})
```